# Merging data frames

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to introduce data with multiple variables of some observations (df2) into another table with all observations and no variables (df1).

```
df1 <- data.table(id = c(100:120))
df2 <- data.table(id = c("100","105","115","120"),
                  x = 1:4,
                  y = c(5:8),
                  z = c(8:11))
```

The outcome would be a table with all ids and data in the maching cells, the rest would be NA.
It seems like a simple task but i dont really know how to get it done

Comment: `left_join(df1, df2)`

Comment: Your merge variable `id` must be the same class, so you either need `df1$id` to be strings, or `df2$id` to be integer. You cannot merge on different class variables. Once that is resolved, then this is just `merge(df1, df2, by = "id", all.x = TRUE)` or `dplyr::left_join(df1, df2, by = "id")`.